# visually wrap at character instead of word boundaries in emacs

Tags: emacs

Using

```
(global-visual-line-mode t)
```

visually wraps long lines at the right edge at the last word boundary (tab or space). But is it possible to visually wrap at characters?

For example, instead of:

```
the quick
brown
```

do:

```
the quick br
own
```

Comment: The default behavior of Emacs is that regular characters are wrapped at the window edge.  The *chiste* [fun part aka reason] of using `visual-line-mode` is that whole words are kept together.  If you want the default behavior of wrapping at any character that touches the window-edge, then don't use `visual-line-mode` -- i.e., remove `(global-visual-line-mode t)`.  The functions `beginning-of-visual-line` and `end-of-visual-line` can be used even when `visual-line-mode` is not active, but you will need to bind those functions to your favorite shortcut keys.

Comment: Ah then it must be something with my emacs (24.5.1) configuration then. Removing `global-visual-line-mode` results in no visual wrapping at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My version of Emacs does this behavior with no customization. That is, from `emacs -Q`, [each line wraps](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Continuation-Lines.html#Continuation-Lines) at the exact character that is at the end of the window. So if you don't want to wrap at word basis, don't turn on `global-visual-line-mode`.

But there are a few variables that influence this. By default, Emacs will truncate lines in windows that are less than 50 characters in width. If this is happening to you, set `truncate-partial-width-windows` to `nil`:

```
(setq truncate-partial-width-windows nil)
```

Similarly, you might look at the variable `truncate-lines`. This controls whether lines are truncated, and is `nil` on my machine, corresponding to "don't truncate".

Comment: My `emacs -Q` also does this behaviour. But with my init.el, removing `global-visual-line-mode` results in no visual line wrapping. Instead, the truncating as explained in your link (which I already saw prior to asking). `(setq truncate-lines nil)` also does not work, i.e. lines are still not visually wrapped.